# iOS - download multiple images at once, best library to use

Tags: ios, image, request, nsurlconnection

For my iPhone app, I have to download approximately 300 images and store them in CoreData for later use. I have those pictures online, as files, stored in a folder on my server. I want to be able to inform the user of the progress, remaining time, and so on.

I have always been using NSURLConnection and it works great, but just for one image. If I try to download multiple images, it will work, but because they are separate requests, I'm not able to inform the user of the progress.

That's why I'd like to use a library to do this, but the one I most liked hasn't been updated since 2011...: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest

What could I do to resolve this issue? Use another library? Or are there any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is Alamofire if you use swift. If you use objective-c there is AFNetworking.
Both have a very simple methods to load the image even asynchronously. You can even track the progress with the framework.

Check these out! these are what you are looking for

[Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire)

[AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

Comment: Good points, but you can also use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage). Especially the property of its manager : `[SDWebImageDownloader sharedDownloader].currentDownloadCount` @JasonNam @user3209448